# Files created by Pandas df.to_csv() cause JupyterLab to throw File Load Error

Tags: pandas, csv, jupyter-lab

Running this: `pd.DataFrame([1,2,3]).to_csv("test.csv")` in a .ipynb, and then trying to open "test.csv" yields `File Load Error for test.csv`. I really am not sure why, since this pretty much changed out of nowhere, and a correct view of "test.csv" even flashes on the screen for a second before it's closed the error is thrown.

I've seen other posts have fixed this by renaming, moving, and copying the file within the JupyterLab browser. None of this works. Any help would be appreciated!